# Convert HTML to PDF with a numbered table of contents

Tags: javascript, java, html, linux, pdf-generation

I want to convert an HTML file to a PDF file using Java or JavaScript. In addition, I want to have a numbered Table of Contents with clickable links.

Currently I am using Playwright to convert an HTML file to a PDF file. It works fine, but the only downside is that it doesn't provide an option to automatically generate a table of contents (as far as I know).

I was looking into other tools such as:
**Pandoc** but I ran into other issues when running the pandoc command:

```
pandoc test.html -t html --css style.css -o test.pdf --toc --metadata title="test"
◴ Loading: ./html2pdf54915-0.htmlError: Could not find Chrome (ver. 115.0.5790.98). This can occur if either
 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or
 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/kali/.cache/puppeteer).
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
    at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/pagedjs-cli/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:274:27)
    at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/pagedjs-cli/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:174:25)
    at ChromeLauncher.computeLaunchArguments (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/pagedjs-cli/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:91:37)
    at async ChromeLauncher.launch (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/pagedjs-cli/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:53:28)
    at async Printer.setup (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/pagedjs-cli/src/printer.js:66:19)
    at async Printer.render (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/pagedjs-cli/src/printer.js:79:4)
    at async Printer.pdf (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/pagedjs-cli/src/printer.js:270:14)
    at async file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/pagedjs-cli/src/cli.js:172:10
Error producing PDF.
```

For some reason it is not able to find chrome, but it is installed...

I was also looking into **wkhtmltopdf**, but wkhtmltopdf doesn't provide a way to generate a table of contents with clickable links and numbering.

So as a workaround, I am trying to just code it using html/javascript. My table of contents looks like this:

```
          <h1>Table of Contents</h1>
          <ol class="toc-list">
            <li><a href="#management-summary">Management Summary</a><span class="pageNumber"></span></li>
            <li><a href="#technical-summary">Technical Summary</a><span class="pageNumber"></span></li>
            <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a><span class="pageNumber"></span></li>
            <li><a href="#vulnerabilities">Vulnerabilities</a><span class="pageNumber"></span></li>
            <ol>
              
                <li>
                  <a href="#vulnerability-1">Cross Site Scripting</a>
                  <span class="pageNumber"></span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#vulnerability-2">SQL Injection</a>
                  <span class="pageNumber"></span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#vulnerability-3">Path traversal</a>
                  <span class="pageNumber"></span>
                </li>
            </ol>
          </ol>
```

This table of contents is clickable, I can for example refer to a section like this:

```
<div id="management-summary">
          <h1>Management Summary</h1>
          <p>The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using &#39;Content here, content here&#39;, making it look like readable English. </p>

        </div>
```

In PDF format, it looks like this:
[image]

This looks okay, but the question is: **how do I add page numbers on the right side of the table of contents?** I know how to add it statically, or by just incrementing the index by 1. However, an html page can be 1 PDF page long but also 1/2/3/4/5/6/7 pages long. So it needs to generate the numbering dynamically. How can I do this using HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Or are there any other tools that allow me to generate a table of contents

Comment: What command do you use for this?